# How to fill date field via Rules in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, datefield, drupal-rules

One content type in my drupal page (*Drupal 7*) has a **date field**. After importing start hour, start minute and duration (*Integer values*) from an XML file, I want to set date field of the node via Rules. It seems that I cannot access the start date, end date, duration and repeating of the date field.

Is there a solution to set the start date, end date, repeating, etc. ?

```
Node A
-- title (text)
-- start minute (integer)
-- start hour (integer)
-- end minute (integer)
-- end hour (integer)
-- duration (integer)
-- days (integer values)

Node B
-- title (text)
-- date (date field)
```

With Rules I want to loop every Node A contents and want to create Node B contents. On creating I want to set the date field with the values of Node A. The date field has options like "start date, end date and repeating". I want to set these values but there are no tokens for "repeating" in Rules.

Node A is just a helper node I used to import my values from an XML file with feeds. Feeds (with XML parser) cannot map different values (minute, hour, duration, repeating) to one date field. So I hope thata Rule could help me. After creating Node B I will delete Node A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use module [scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler)

If your requirement is very specific, you can use execute php code under the action and update database records using query

Cheers!!!

Comment: But the scheduler modules isn't responsible to access the date field or? I want to set the start date as: "01.01.2011", the duration in minutes or hours (30 or 0,5).

Comment: this might help you then [fieldscheduler](http://drupal.org/project/fieldscheduler)

Comment: It doesn't look if you understood my problem. I will update my top posting in a minute.